# Where can I find an implementation of Java EL 3.0

Tags: java, collections, lambda, el, spring-el

The Expression Language version 3.0 is currently being designed. It adds various cool features like mapping and filtering collections by a lambda expression. Spring EL has a comparable feature which does not use lambdas though.

Despite googling for a (reference) implementation of EL3 I couldn't find anything, Is there an (reference) implementation available or at least underway?

Otherwise I may need to use Spring EL for now, I guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was anywhere it would be at the JSR 341 home page. Their source repo is here http://java.net/projects/el-spec/sources/source-code/show but it doesn't look like they've got as far as a reference implementation yet (the trunk POM has `3.0-b02-SNAPSHOT`).

Comment: Wait! There's <http://java.net/projects/el-spec/sources/source-code/show/trunk/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/el/>

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of Expression Language 3.0 (JSR 341) used in Glassfish is available in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22org.glassfish%22%20AND%20a:%22javax.el%22

As mentioned by artbristol, the source code of the reference implementation may be found on the spec's site. The exact URL for the 3.0 release is:
https://java.net/projects/el-spec/sources/source-code/show/tags/javax.el-3.0.0/impl?rev=285